# Is it possible to make a video app preview for iPhone6+ without an iPhone6+?

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, iphone-6-plus

The title pretty much says it all: do I need to go out and purchase an iPhone6+ to make a video app preview for it, or is it possible to do it on the simulator? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on whether your app is functional enough and performs well enough on the simulator to produce a good video. QuickTime Player (and plenty of third-party Mac apps) can do screen recording, so you could do a recording of the simulator window.